# Updating a field according to text-box change jQuery

Tags: jquery, event-handling, textchanged

I wrote a program to change the value of a field when the user type a value in text-boxes. In my case the 2 text-boxes are height and width. When someone enter a height and width relevant price should be shown. I'll put my coding down below.

```
<div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-9">
          <input type="text" id="height" />
          <input type="text" id="width" />


          <button type="button" id="show">Enter Size</button>
<button type="button" id="hide">Hide</button>

<script> jQuery('height').on('input', function() {
    <?php echo "hello" ?>


});

function()
{
    <input id="post_price" type="hidden" name="price" value="<?=$price['price'];?>">
}
</script>

        </div>
      </div>
```

I'm not exactly sure the way I did. There are no output results at the moment. Could someone help me? To make more sense I'll attach a screenshot of my form. Thanks! [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `keydown` or `keypress` event.
I made a little exemple [here](https://jsfiddle.net/LxLrxbej/)